# Is the order in which answers of the same rank get listed well defined?

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting

It seems like when I ask a question and refresh the page, then answers of the same rank can appear in any order, and they often do.  Is this behavior well defined?

Since I am not yet at the reputation required to see up and down votes, I am curious if answers that were only up-voted are given a higher priority than ones that were both up and down voted?  Or maybe ordered by the answerer's reputation?  Or their total number of accepted answers? Or anything at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they have the same net score, and you are ordering *by score* then the sub-sort is defined: as intentionally random.

Comment: Then it appears to be working perfectly as defined. Is there no extra criterion that could improve this randomness? Can I order by something other than score?

Comment: @Jimmy sure; there are three tabs between the question and answer; "active" | "oldest" | "votes".. If you mean "as a sub-sort", then by design: no